# How to overwrite a file with pyspark in Azure Spark Cluster

Tags: azure, python, apache-spark

I'm using the following script to output the results of a SPARQL query to a file in Azure Data Store. However, instead of creating a file called `myresults.json` and publishing the results to the `myresults.json` file, the script publishes the results to a random file name like `part-0000-tid` like in the image below:

[image: pyspark]

The code is as follows:

```
example1 = spark.sql("""SELECT
  CF.CountryName AS CountryCarsSold
 ,COUNT(CF.CountryName) AS NumberCountry
 ,MAX(CB.SalesDetailsID) AS TotalSold
FROM Data_SalesDetails CB
INNER JOIN Data_Sales CD
  ON CB.SalesID = CD.SalesID
INNER JOIN Data_Customer CG
  ON CD.CustomerID = CG.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Data_Country CF
  ON CG.Country = CF.CountryISO2
GROUP BY CF.CountryName""")
example1.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").json("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/jfolder2/outputfiles/myoutput3/myresults.json")
```

Can someone let me know how to save as a single file and each file is overwritten each time it is saved.

Thanks